# Renaming _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to configure Razor to look for "master" layout files named other than `_ViewStart.cshtml`? I mean, without explicitly setting the `Layout` property in the content templates.

In the project I'm working on, each [area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=VS.98).aspx) has its own `_ViewStart.cshtml`. On top of them there's a "global" `_ViewStart.cshtml`. This works fine, but I think it would be more convenient if I could assign different names for each master template, like calling the "global" template `_GlobalViewStart.cshtml`. That way it would be easier to spot each file when there are many of them open on the Visual Studio ribbon. (Silly? Perhaps.)

If it's possible, how can one do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your scenario? Whatever your final goal is, there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that myself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard coded in the `RazorViewEngine` as "_ViewStart" so I doubt it unless you compile your own version.

```
public class RazorViewEngine : BuildManagerViewEngine {
    internal static readonly string ViewStartFileName = "_ViewStart";
}
```

You could define your own base View that changes Layout to whatever you want so you don't have to modify it on every view.

Comment: I was wishfully thinking that there were some web.config tweak. But I can live without it, thanks.

Comment: you could always change it with reflection :P

Comment: I was also looking for this. Can't understand why would they choose "_ViewStart" instead of "index" and then hardcode it. Part of the EEE plan, i guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

Umm, just saying but isn't the whole point of _ViewStart that its a central place to define settings for all pages (in the area). Note this doesn't mean its a masterpage.

Normally you would specify the default masterpage for the area in _ViewStart, by default this is _Layout (which is your masterpage)